# Web Socket Secure URL Encryption

Tags: javascript, ruby, encryption, websocket, sinatra

Is the URL itself encrypted as well when using `wss://`? For example, say you have a simple Sinatra web application that accepts web socket connections:

```
class App < Sinatra::Base

  get "/ws/:api_key/room/:id" do |api_key, id|
    user = User.find_by(api_key: api_key)
    room = Room.find(id)

    if RoomAuthenticator.new(room).authorized?(user)
      request.websocket do |ws|
        ws.onopen { publish(room, "#{user.name} connected.") }
      end
    else
      401
    end
  end
end
```

Then from the client/browser, in JavaScript:

```
new WebSocket("wss://" + window.location.host + "/ws/" + user.api_key + "/room/" + room.id);
```

Is the `user.api_key` in the URL encrypted or is it susceptible to attacks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the URL will be encrypted. Secure web sockets use Transport Layer Security (just like HTTPS does) to tunnel all data over the secure connection. See [section 4 of RFC 6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#page-17):

> If /secure/ is true, the client MUST perform a TLS handshake over the
> connection after opening the connection and before sending the
> handshake data. [...] all further communication on this channel MUST run through the encrypted tunnel.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I wasn't sure whether passing in the `api_key` through the `wss://` URL would be a safe way transfer this information. It doesn't seem to be possible to use query parameters (e.g. `?api_key=VALUE`) or headers (e.g. `x-api-key: VALUE`) through web sockets.